# My `nextLetter` mouseover function doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

What I want my code to do is when I pass with my mouse on my text, the next letters of the alphabet appear. I created the function `nextLetter` but it doesn’t work.

```js
var conteneur = document.querySelector('.texte2')
var textBalise = conteneur.textContent.replace(/(\S)/g, '<span class = x>$1</span>')

conteneur.innerHTML = textBalise

var $spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')
const ch = 'a'

function nextLetter(ch) {
  if (!ch.match(/[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]/i)) return ch;
  else if (ch === 'Z') return 'A';
  else if (ch === 'z') return 'A';
  
  return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}

for (var $span of $spans) {
  $span.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    console.log(nextLetter)
  });
}
```

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're not passing the character under the mouse to the `nextLetter` function.

```
console.log(nextLetter)
```

will output the definition of the function, not call it - you need to add `()` to call the function.

The letter under the cursor is:  `e.currentTarget.textContent`, giving

```
for (var $span of $spans) {
  $span.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    console.log(nextLetter(e.currentTarget.textContent))
  });
}
```

Put together, your code becomes:

```js
var conteneur = document.querySelector('.texte2')
var textBalise = conteneur.textContent.replace(/(\S)/g, '\<span\>$1\</span\>')
//console.log(textBalise)
conteneur.innerHTML = textBalise

var $spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')
// not used: const ch = 'a'

function nextLetter(ch) {
  if (!ch.match(/[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]/i)) return ch;
  else if (ch === 'Z') return 'A';
  else if (ch === 'z') return 'a';
  return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}

for (var $span of $spans) {
  $span.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    //console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent)
    console.log(nextLetter(e.currentTarget.textContent))
  });
}
```

```html
<div class='texte2'>This is a test</div>
```

Comment: Thank u so much! I have an another question because i don't want the result are only in the console, i want the letters change in the text too, want can i do for that ?

Comment: Please accept this answer as it solves your issue as asked in the question; you can then ask a new question as a follow on.  Having said that, the basic solution is: `e.currentTarget.textContent = nextLetter(e.currentTarget.textContent)` but needs clarifying if you want it to be able to change back, or if you want it to keep "next-ing" whenever the mouse is over (as you're using mouseover not mouseenter) - so would be best in its own question.

Comment: ok i made a new topic!